# R moving average

Tags: r, moving-average

As an example I use the `Boston` data with 3 columns (id (added), medv, lstat) and 506 observations.

I want to calculate a moving average for k-1 observations for the variable medv. This means that the mean value should be calculated over all observations except a certain row. For id 1, the mean value is calculated from line 2-506. For id 2, the mean value is calculated over line 1 + 3-506. For id 3, the mean value is calculated over the lines 1-2 + 4-506 and so on.

In a second step the calculation of the mean value should be conditional, e.g. above the median and below the median in two different columns. This means that we first check whether a value within each column (medv and lstat) is above or below the median. If the value in medv is above the median, we calculate the mean value of lstat from the values that are above the median in lstat. If the value in medv is below the median, we calculate the mean value of lstat from the values that are below the median. See example table below for the first 10 rows. The median for the first 10 rows is 25.55 for medv and 7.24 for lstat.

Here is the data:

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
df <- BostonHousing
df$id <- seq.int(nrow(df))
df <- subset(df, select = c(id, medv, lstat))
```

```
id medv lstat mean1out meancond
 1 24.0  4.98 26.66667     4.50
 2 21.6  9.14 26.93333     4.50
 3 34.7  4.03 25.47778    17.55
 4 33.4  2.94 25.62222    17.55
 5 36.2  5.33 25.31111    17.55
 6 28.7  5.21 26.14444    17.55
 7 22.9 12.43 26.78889     4.50
 8 27.1 19.15 26.32222    17.55
 9 16.5 29.93 27.50000     4.50
10 18.9 17.10 27.23333     4.50
```

Comment: Can you reduce your `df` to say 10 rows, calculate the expected output by hand and update your post. I am not sure if I understand your second step.

Comment: I edited the article and clarified the second step with a numerical example.

Comment: How do you get first value as `26.66667` ? 24 is less than the median of that column which is 25.55. Now if we take mean of all the values which are less than median in the column we get `mean(df$medv[df$medv < med_val])` which is `20.78`.

Comment: The value 26.66667 is the value from the first step, which is the moving average of k-1 observations from medv. In this particular case, it represents the mean value from the medv column for id 2-10 (240/9). Only the meancond column represents the expected result of the second step.

Comment: Shouldn't second value in `meancond` be 17.55 then since `lsat` value 9.14 which is greater than 7.24.

Comment: No, 4.50 is right. Because I check if the value in medv is smaller than the median. If this is the case, I intend to calculate the mean value in lstat based on the values, which are smaller than the median in lstat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the problem is already solved by @r2evans.

For the second part we can calculate `median` of `lstat` and `medv`, compare and assign values.

```
#First part from @r2evans answer. 
n <- nrow(df)
df$mean1out <- (mean(df$medv)*n - df$medv)/(n-1)


#Second part
med_lsat <- median(df$lstat)
med_medv <- median(df$medv)
higher_lsat <- mean(df$lstat[df$lstat > med_lsat])
lower_lsat <- mean(df$lstat[df$lstat < med_lsat])
df$meancond <- ifelse(df$medv > med_medv, higher_lsat, lower_lsat)
df

#   id medv lstat mean1out meancond
#1   1 24.0  4.98 26.66667    4.498
#2   2 21.6  9.14 26.93333    4.498
#3   3 34.7  4.03 25.47778   17.550
#4   4 33.4  2.94 25.62222   17.550
#5   5 36.2  5.33 25.31111   17.550
#6   6 28.7  5.21 26.14444   17.550
#7   7 22.9 12.43 26.78889    4.498
#8   8 27.1 19.15 26.32222   17.550
#9   9 16.5 29.93 27.50000    4.498
#10 10 18.9 17.10 27.23333    4.498
```

**data**

```
df <- BostonHousing
df$id <- seq.int(nrow(df))
df <- subset(df, select = c(id, medv, lstat))
df <- head(df, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
mean(dat$medv[-3])
# [1] 25.47778

sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), function(i) mean(dat$medv[-i]))
#  [1] 26.66667 26.93333 25.47778 25.62222 25.31111 26.14444 26.78889 26.32222 27.50000 27.23333
```

Alternatively (mathematically), without the `sapply`, you can get the same numbers this way:

```r
n <- nrow(dat)
(mean(dat$medv)*n - dat$medv)/(n-1)
#  [1] 26.66667 26.93333 25.47778 25.62222 25.31111 26.14444 26.78889 26.32222 27.50000 27.23333
```

For your conditional mean, a simple `ifelse` works:

```r
n <- nrow(dat)
transform(
  dat,
  a = (mean(dat$medv)*n - dat$medv)/(n-1),
  b = ifelse(medv <= median(medv),
             mean(lstat[ lstat <= median(lstat) ]),
             mean(lstat[ lstat > median(lstat) ]))
)
#    id medv lstat mean1out meancond        a      b
# 1   1 24.0  4.98 26.66667     4.50 26.66667  4.498
# 2   2 21.6  9.14 26.93333     4.50 26.93333  4.498
# 3   3 34.7  4.03 25.47778    17.55 25.47778 17.550
# 4   4 33.4  2.94 25.62222    17.55 25.62222 17.550
# 5   5 36.2  5.33 25.31111    17.55 25.31111 17.550
# 6   6 28.7  5.21 26.14444    17.55 26.14444 17.550
# 7   7 22.9 12.43 26.78889     4.50 26.78889  4.498
# 8   8 27.1 19.15 26.32222    17.55 26.32222 17.550
# 9   9 16.5 29.93 27.50000     4.50 27.50000  4.498
# 10 10 18.9 17.10 27.23333     4.50 27.23333  4.498
```

(I'm inferring that the differences are rounding errors on data entry.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I was a bit unclear about the filtering. I do not want to filter out the rows that are larger than the median, but I want to calculate the mean value only over these rows. This means that I still calculate a value for all ids. But it includes only the lines, which are larger than the median.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's not clear. Please include expected output given your input data.

Comment: I edited the article and clarified the second step with a numerical example.